# Web Site Thumbnail?

Tags: asp.net

I posted a link of my website on facebook, but it uses an image for a thumbnail that 
I don't want(it is an image inside my website). How can I govern which thumbnail is used for my web site on any web page(facebook etc) ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

For facebook at least, use <link rel="image_src" href="your_image.jpg">

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is this for every page in my web site or just the home page?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not work, fb does not pick it up for a thumbnail. This is the code in my default.aspx(homepage)...under the head tag- <link href="http://trapsuutjie.dyndns-home.com/images/chameleon.jpg" rel="image_src">. Chameleon.jpg is the thumbnail I want to have displayed on fb

Comment: sorry, I meant <link rel="image_src" href="http://trapsuutjie.dyndns-home.com/images/chameleon.jpg" />